# Don't need the App Store to make apps anymore?

Tags: ios, web-applications, mobile-safari

I recently found a site that allowed me to bookmark the site and then use it just like an app. There was no url bar, it was indistinguishable from an app you would download on App Store. Is this a new upgrade or technology ?

Comment: Confusing title (needs attention). You're probably talking about responsive web sites. Check out - https://fbf8.com/ on Safari. Is that what you're talking about?

Answer (score 3):

This is not new technology, I don't remember how long it's been out, but I'm pretty sure at least since iOS 3. It's called a webclip. You can do quite a bit with a webclip but are still limited to functionality provided by JavaScript, so no accessing the flashlight and certain hardware features (although many are being included in the device JS object). Though it is certainly much easier to implement basic app functionality!

Answer (score 1):

+1 to SnoApps and here's a bit more detail about this older detail.

You can specify a webpage to appear like a regular app icon on the iPhone "home" screen (where all the apps appear).

There's more information here under the ["Configuring Web Application" section of this Apple Safari Web Content Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW3).